Delphi 12, Bluetooth connection between two Android devices, where sockets are running in threads, gets error: Channel is closed, cannot read data
When my Bluetooth client socket and server socket are running in separate threads (I have 3 threads at the same time: Main thread, Client socket thread, Server socket thread) and communication is between two Android devices, I always get an error message:

Channel is closed, cannot read data

Combination of Windows 11 and Android works properly in both directions. Problem is only between two Android devices.
Tested on real devices with Android (v12, v14), Windows 11. Delphi 12 CE (project for multi-device application)
Bluetooth permissions are set:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

(Next sources are not final, they are simplified as much as possible, but working)
Socket threads are created in main thread by click on buttons:
procedure TForm1.btnBTServerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  BTServerThread: TBTServerThread;
begin
  BTServerThread := TBTServerThread.Create('MyAppServerSocket', DM.BT_GUID, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnBTClientClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  BTDevice: TBluetoothDevice;
  BTClientThread: TBTClientThread;
begin
  BTDevice := self.getDevice(ComboBox1.Text);
  BTClientThread := TBTClientThread.Create(BTDevice, DM.BT_GUID, True, Edit1.Text);
end;

Server socket thread:
unit BTServerThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Bluetooth, System.SysUtils;

type
  TBTServerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    ServerSocket: TBluetoothServerSocket;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ServerName: string; GUID: TGUID; Secure: boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses MainScreen;

procedure TBTServerThread.Execute;
var
  ClientSocket: TBluetoothSocket;
  ReceivedData: TBytes;
  StringData: String;
begin
  Synchronize(procedure begin Form1.memoLog.Lines.Add('start') end);
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try
      ClientSocket := self.ServerSocket.Accept(2000);
      if Assigned(ClientSocket) then
      begin
        ReceivedData := ClientSocket.ReceiveData;
        StringData := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ReceivedData);
        Synchronize(procedure begin Form1.memoLog.Lines.Add(StringData); end);
      end;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        Synchronize(procedure begin Form1.memoLog.Lines.Add('Exception: ' + E.Message) end);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

constructor TBTServerThread.Create(ServerName: string; GUID: TGUID; Secure: boolean);
var
  BluetoothManager: TBluetoothManager;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  self.ServerSocket := TBluetoothManager.Current.CreateServerSocket(ServerName, GUID, Secure);

  Resume;
end;

destructor TBTServerThread.Destroy;
begin
  self.ServerSocket.Close;
  inherited;
end;

end.

Client socket thread:
unit BTClientThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Bluetooth, System.SysUtils;

type
  TBTClientThread = class(TThread)
  private
    ClientSocket: TBluetoothSocket;
    Msg: String;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Device: TBluetoothDevice; GUID: TGUID;
      Secure: Boolean; Msg: String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation


procedure TBTClientThread.Execute;
var
  DataToSend: TBytes;
begin
  self.ClientSocket.Connect;
  if self.ClientSocket.Connected then
  begin
    DataToSend := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(self.Msg);
    self.ClientSocket.SendData(DataToSend);
  end;
end;

constructor TBTClientThread.Create(Device: TBluetoothDevice; GUID: TGUID;
  Secure: Boolean; Msg: String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  self.Msg := Msg;
  self.ClientSocket :=  Device.CreateClientSocket(GUID, Secure);

  Resume;
end;

destructor TBTClientThread.Destroy;
begin
  ClientSocket.Close;
  inherited;
end;

end.

When Client socket is running from main thread, it works properly between Android-Android, and Android-Windows devices as well.
But, I would like to have both sockets running from separate threads because of user experience.
